# Bind a service variable to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller which contains a function that gets some data from the server. I store that data in a service variable. This service is then injected into a directive. I want the directive to be auto updated, whenever this function is called and the data is renewed.

My controller:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'SomeService', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.update = function() {
        SomeService.myValue = 100;
    }
}]);
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myDirective', ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
    return {
        templateUrl : 'views/myDirective.html',
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : false,
        controller : function($scope) {
            this.myValue = SomeService.myValue;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The template:

```
<div>
    {{ myValue }}
</div>
```

The update function is called when a button is clicked and it updates myValue to a new value. I want it to be automatically reflected in the directive.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/OUPzT4MFS32OenRIO9q4?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see working demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, SomeService) {
  $scope.name = SomeService.data;

  $scope.update = function() {

    $scope.name.myValue += 1;
  }

});

app.factory('SomeService', function() {
  var data = {

    myValue: 0

  };

  return {

    data: data

  }
});


app.directive('myDirective', ['SomeService',
  function(SomeService) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'myDirective.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        scope.data = SomeService.data

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>My Value: {{name.myValue}}</p>
    <button ng-click="update()">Click</button>
    <hr/>
    <div my-directive></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
      <h3>My Directive</h3>
      <p>Value: {{data.myValue}}</p>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed this, I can access the data in the link function. But surprisingly, I can't see it in the directive!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde can you please tell me where exactly ?

Comment: That and one more thing... I'm not assigning a controller explicitly to the directive. The data I'm using in the directive is an object. I can see it available in the link function. But when I use it in the directive's template, it's not visible.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde now I'm completely confused what are you looking for

Comment: Using your code, `myValue` is accessible in the directive's link function. But when I do `{{ myValue }}` in the template, it is not appearing.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde you can access it via `{{data.myValue}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64330/discussion-between-sylwester-and-rutwick-gangurde).

Answer (score 3):

You can try by adding the reference of the service to the directive itself..

The directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myDirective', ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
    return {
        templateUrl : 'views/myDirective.html',
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : false,
        controller : function($scope) {
            this.SomeService = SomeService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The template:

```
<div>
    {{ SomeService.myValue }}
</div>
```

> Edit : I went through your plunker, and have finally got it working.

You can check the updated code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2UhZplZnEqCxly5fbTKT?p=preview)

Comment: This is what I would also do. No additional watcher, just native JS object reference.

Comment: Can you post a plunker for the same @RutwickGangurde ??

Comment: Try `$scope.SomeService = SomeService;`

Comment: How will that make a difference @dfsq ??

Comment: I have added a plunker, but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @TechMa9iac Please check the plunker, I really need to solve this!

Comment: The binding doesn't update, even in a normal template! I had to broadcast an event and watch it to update the binding, then it worked!

Comment: Thanks! I tried the exact way as your plunk, but the binding doesn't update automatically, I had to emit an event to the parent scope to update it.

Answer (score 1):

@RutwickGangurde and others who were having issues, if you're trying to set a scope variable that is not an object it won't work. I'm guessing that's what you're currently doing in your service:

```
...
this.myVar = true;
...
```

and then trying to set it in the directive/controller:

```
...
scope.myVar = myService.myVar;
...
```

That will NOT work for getting the updated variable in the service when it changes.

Try this instead in your service:

```
...
this.myObj = {};
this.myObj.myVar = true;
...
```

and in your directive/controller:

```
...
scope.myValue = myService.myObj;
...
```

and in your html:

```
...
{{ myValue.myVar }}
...
```

I would have made this as a comment, but I don't have sufficient privileges yet so decided to post as a response with a very brief example.